# Почему удаляются кнопки, а не виджеты Label и Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Нумерация")

fr=Frame(root)
fr.grid()
kom_kv=Label(root,text='Введите номер квартиры с несколькими собственниками:')
kom_kv.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=W)
kom_kv1=Entry(root)
kom_kv1.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)

sobs=Label(root,text='Введите колличество собственников:')
sobs.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
sobs1=Entry(root)
sobs1.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)

def addFlat():
    fr=Frame(root)
    fr.grid()
    kom_kv=Label(fr,text='Введите номер квартиры с несколькими собственниками:')
    kom_kv.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=W)
    kom_kv1=Entry(fr)
    kom_kv1.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)

    sobs=Label(fr,text='Введите колличество собственников:')
    sobs.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
    sobs1=Entry(fr)
    sobs1.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)


def deleteFlat():
    fr.grid_remove()
    kom_kv.grid_remove()
    kom_kv1.grid_remove()
    sobs.grid_remove()
    sobs1.grid_remove()


plus=Button(fr,text='Добавить квартиру', command=addFlat)
plus.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)

plus=Button(fr,text='Удалить квартиру', command=deleteFlat)
plus.grid(row=10, column=2, sticky=W)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: потому что вы привязываете кнопки к фрейму, а `Label` и `Entry` к `root`

Comment: Если  уберу все frame，и привяжу все к root，то label и entry все равно не удаляются

Comment: [Ну как вариант](https://github.com/Cmertho/Python_project/blob/master/PyQt5_project/user327535.py) (если он вам вообще подходит)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что работало неправильно: Функция удаления всегда ссылалась на последний фрейм с его компонентами

```
def deleteFlat():
    fr.grid_remove()
    kom_kv.grid_remove()
    kom_kv1.grid_remove()
    sobs.grid_remove()
    sobs1.grid_remove()
```

Как исправить: можно хранить в стеке фреймы - записывать по кнопке Добавить и удалять по другой кнопке, вот пример кода:

```
class UI:
    sobsList = []
    sobs1List = []

    komKvList = []
    komKv1List = []

    frList = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Нумерация")

        self.fr = Frame(self.root)
        self.fr.grid()

        self.plus = Button(self.fr, text='Добавить квартиру', command=self.addFlat)
        self.plus.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.plus = Button(self.fr, text='Удалить квартиру', command=self.deleteFlat)
        self.plus.grid(row=10, column=2, sticky=W)

        self.addFlat()

    def addFlat(self):
        fr = Frame(self.root)
        fr.grid()
        self.frList.append(fr)
        self.fr = fr

        kom_kv = Label(self.fr, text='Введите номер квартиры с несколькими собственниками:')
        kom_kv.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.komKvList.append(kom_kv)

        kom_kv1 = Entry(self.fr)
        kom_kv1.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)
        self.komKv1List.append(kom_kv1)

        sobs = Label(self.fr,text='Введите колличество собственников:')
        sobs.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
        self.sobsList.append(sobs)

        sobs1=Entry(self.fr)
        sobs1.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
        self.sobs1List.append(sobs1)

    def deleteFlat(self):
        self.frList.pop().grid_remove()
        self.komKvList.pop().grid_remove()
        self.komKv1List.pop().grid_remove()
        self.sobsList.pop().grid_remove()
        self.sobs1List.pop().grid_remove()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ui = UI()
    ui.root.mainloop()
```

Таким образом по кнопке удаления будет удаляться очередной фрейм из интерфейса, сколько бы их создано небыло